# How can I modify the current value of a DB context entity prior to saving changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm doing db first modeling in Entity Framework and for simplicity sake let's just say I have two related tables

My entity classes are

```
public partial class JournalEntryCode
{
    public JournalEntryCode()
    {
        this.JournalEntries = new HashSet<JournalEntry>();
    }

    public int journal_entry_code_pk { get; set; }
    public string journal_entry_code { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime tstamp { get; set; }  

    public virtual ICollection<JournalEntry> JournalEntries { get; set; }  
}
```

and

```
public partial class JournalEntry
{
    public long journal_entry_pk { get; set; }
    public int journal_entry_code_pk { get; set; }
    public string journal_entry { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime tstamp { get; set; }

    public virtual JournalEntryCode JournalEntryCode { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what I am trying to do..

During the `SaveChanges` method I want to add in a process that loops through any modified entry in the `DbContext` and updates the `tstamp` property of each modified entry to reflect a single `tstamp` value set at the instant that `SaveChanges` is called... is there an easy way to do this?

So let's say that in `JournalEntryCode` db context I have two records one with `journal_entry_code_pk` of 2 and the other of `journal_entry_code_pk` of 5  and they are both modified on their `journal_entry_code` properties

I want to set both of those entries `tstamp` values for the current values at the same value of

```
DateTime tstamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

I cant figure out how to modify the current state value of the `tstamp` property for the records in the context though.

Comment: What's the purpose of `tstamp`? There is a timestamp feature built into sql server if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to define an interface like

```
public interface ITimeStamped
{
    DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

and make `JournalEntry` and  `JournalEntryCode` implement it. Entity Framework will (and can) not use the interface, but you can, for instance in an override of `SaveChanges` in your context class.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    DateTime tstamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var timeStampedEntities = this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                                  .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added
                                           || e.State == EntityState.Modified)
                                  .Select(e => e.Entity).OfType<ITimeStamped>();
    foreach (var timeStamped in timeStampedEntities)
    {
        timeStamped.TimeStamp = tstamp;
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

But you should be (and maybe are) aware of the fact that small differences in clocks on client machines may make this timestamp unreliable when it comes to the exact order of events. Also, a big transaction may take considerable more time than a small one, so a small transaction may finish earlier with a later timestamp than a large transaction. If this is meant to be a super reliable mechanism you should probably look into Sql Server auditing.

Comment: works perfectly thanks!  Cant use sql because the system is actually writing across multiple databases and whats important more so than an exactness of time is duplicate time value for each entry that gets written..also its not just a timestamp I need there are few other audit related columns that have to be filled using the same process. I just kept it simple for the sake of the example and used only the timestamp property.  Anyway like i said works perfect thank a bundle for the help ;)